# docker image not running cent os

Tags: linux, docker, centos

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
13be43ecefea        196e0ce0c9fb                   "/bin/bash"              About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                       reverent_wing
ff1b2744bf2c        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/mssq"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                       ecstatic_brattain
d3504f132ddd        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/mssq"   2 hours ago         Exited (1) 2 hours ago                             compassionate_cray
```

i am new to the docker, i have installed the docker on cent os 7. i have downloaded MSsql and centos image.  when i run the container. it exited with out any info.  can any one help to resolve this

Comment: Post your `docker run` command and `docker ps`

Comment: `docker logs <container>`?

Comment: Post how you ran the command, you may have missed adding the needed environment variables

Comment: Hi Thanks all, i have fixed myself, i have not allotted proper memory to the VM.. thats why its exited. now i have allotted required memory and its working fine. thx Alex and Tarun Lalwain ..  Now i am just testing windows and linux both the contrarians.  some .net app is using windows container and DB and other APIs are running on linux container.  so i like to configure both linux and windows are in swarm mode.  using Docker stack deploy.